# Is it possible to reply to Google+ comments via email?

Tags: google-plus

When people reply to a Google+ post of mine or mention me, I get an email.  On at least one of those emails, I was able to reply via email.  That doesn't seem to be working any more and now messages say "you can't reply to this email".  Is there a way to restore this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reply to the comment right within the email message.

> Gmail and Google plus just got a little closer, with the search giant
>   announcing that you can now use Gmail to respond to Google plus
>   notifications.
>
> The changes mean that Google social’s networking site which has
>   already been integrated into search results,  will also become an
>   important part of Gmail.
>
> So what will it mean for users? Well they can reply to Google plus
>   notifications instantly from their Gmail inbox without having to click
>   on the Plus icon on the Google bar.

More at the official announcement:
http://googleplus-update.blogspot.com/2012/05/now-reply-to-google-plus-comments-from.html

Comment: Thanks.  You're right: http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2609151&topic=1356212&ctx=topic  The issue must be a result of me not using gmail.  =( Thanks.